# Communicate project structure with android using XML?

Tags: android, xml, webserver

### What I'm Trying to Do

I'm trying to create something that will allow customers to customize how our android application will be set up. This should be a UI editor that sits on our web server and, upon save, will communicate with our android project so that it can set itself up.

### What I've Done So Far

I've been looking into something like a Business Project Management tool that can export itself as an XML (or equivalent). For example : https://demo.bpmn.io/new ... The file that even a simple diagram produces (BPMN) seems far more complicated than what we need, though.

### What I Need

We can create something on our own or customize an open source project like this to better fit our needs, but I'm not sure if BPMN is the best approach and I've been having trouble finding sources to learn more about it. Is there a better approach I can take?

My project is still in its very early stages and I would like to make sure I'm at least starting off on a good path.

Comment: Do you have you use a flowchart paradigm or can you use something like Scratch which is open source (with a business friendly color palette)? In some of your more recent posts it appears that a desktop app is acceptable - have you looked at Dia Diagram Editor? Note: if the customization gets complex you are in essence building a full IDE/toolchain and the project should be scoped/cost estimate appropriately.

Comment: Scratch? Do you mean this? https://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Scratch_Source_Code ... We actually want to put this thing up on a web server, but what I'm looking for really is a way to communicate data over different platforms, ie from some sort of ui editor like bpmn to a java program

Comment: Correct MIT Scratch. If you are communicating data, just use a standard webservice. I feel that you are trying to find a silver bullet solution where there is none or using the wrong tool to model what you want. BPMN explains to stakeholders what's going on. It isn't a Data Flow Diagram, UML or for code generation. Your thread is lacking the specificity that StackOverflow is good at. I would go back to your stakeholders and get a clear definition of what the user can and importantly cannot do with the tool and then find/buy/build appropriately.